# Batch script network file

Tags: scripting, batch-file, command

I have a batch script which I am trying to open a file (powershell script on a network location). If I put the path as a local c:\test.ps1 it works fine but I cant seem to get it to work with the network file structure.

```
@echo off 
(set/p adminuser=Enter Your Admin Account: ) 
runas /user:%userdomain%\%adminuser% "powershell "\\Server\share$\IT Support\Test\Test Share\test.ps1""
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: checked path is accessible to user account?

Comment: Certainly is... Not sure if its because the file path has spaces in but just cant get it to work sadly.

Comment: what happens if you try powershell -executionpolicy bypass "\\Server\share$\IT Support\Test\Test Share\test.ps1" ?

Comment: Are you running this from a workstation or a server? What errors or messages do you get?

Comment: Still wont run, just closes down the command prompt. If I put in a local short path it works fine so it def the path thats the issue althrough the path is perfectly correct.

Comment: Matt, from a work station but with domain admin rights. Annoying it works with c:\test.ps1 but not with c:\test share\test.ps1 either so it def the path issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off 
(set/p adminuser=Enter Your Admin Account: ) 
runas /user:%userdomain%\%adminuser% "powershell -noexit & '\\Server\share$\IT Support\Test\Test Share\test.ps1'"
```

Comment: Matt you are a bloody legend. wracked my brains over that. Thanks you dude.